# Teradata to Snowflake conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

Working on Teradata ddl conversion where i could see below code :

Would like to know how to convert from Teradata to Snowflake of below Latin to Unicode DDL code :

```
OTRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(acc_name USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR),'?;*<>"$+()&@#''-/\!','') AS deal_name
```

Comment: TRANSLATE is Standard SQL to change the character sets. As SF stores in UTF-8 only there's no LATIN characters -> no need to translate. And oTranslate is the Teradata specific name for the TRANSLATE function found in most DBMSes includign SF.

Comment: Thanks for the response. so u mean to say that unicode refers to utf-8. as im trying to convert teradata script to snwoflake from your response i could  understand it is not required not convert this snippet. Please correct

Comment: Teradata varchars might be stored in LATIN or UICODE and TRANSLATE can be used to change the character set for data which is already loaded. But SF stores UTF-8 only, thus the data is already translated during import.